# Checked checkbox background not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have used background color for checked checkbox through jQuery. My background color is adding only if i click any checkbox but not already clicked checkbox by default & i don't know why my class is not working on clicked checkbox by default.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*checkbox-background*/
  $(".checkbox-primary").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
    }
  });
  /*checkbox-background-ends*/
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.checkbox>label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #686868;
  padding-top: 2px;
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.checkbox>span {
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.fltr-chk-box-bg {
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  z-index: -7523;
}

.fltr-panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fltr-panel {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.fltr-panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.fltr-panel-title>a {
  padding: 18px 8px 19px 8px;
  font-size: 1.21em;
  color: #2B3439;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel.fltr-panel {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.panel-group.fltr-panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body.fltr-panel-body {
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset {
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.78em;
}

.fltr-and-reset>.pull-right {
  font-size: 1.07em;
  color: #1E6C97;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.fltr-and-reset>.text-left {
  font-size: 1.14em;
  color: #302F2F;
  line-height: 1.647;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">75</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">98</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South Asia</label><span class="pull-right">47</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">53</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">55</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">26</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">78</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">90</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">67</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">88</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: lol, ths question isnt duplicate @CSS ''background-color" attribute not working on checkbox inside <div>@.

if i understand correctly, this guy asks about how to save checkbox value in cookie. You can use HTML5 Web Storage or Jquery Cookie

Comment: add this before Click fucntion  - $(".checkbox input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().addClass("fltr-chk-box-bg"); -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code inside your `document.ready()` Which will loop through all the `checked` input and add the class.

```
$("input:checked").each(function(){
   $(this).parent().addClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
});
```

Like the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*checkbox-background*/
  $(".checkbox-primary").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
    } else {
      $(this).parent().removeClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
    }
  });
  /*checkbox-background-ends*/
  
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("fltr-chk-box-bg");
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.checkbox>label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #686868;
  padding-top: 2px;
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.checkbox>span {
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.fltr-chk-box-bg {
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  z-index: -7523;
}

.fltr-panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fltr-panel {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.fltr-panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.fltr-panel-title>a {
  padding: 18px 8px 19px 8px;
  font-size: 1.21em;
  color: #2B3439;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel.fltr-panel {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.panel-group.fltr-panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body.fltr-panel-body {
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset {
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.78em;
}

.fltr-and-reset>.pull-right {
  font-size: 1.07em;
  color: #1E6C97;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.fltr-and-reset>.text-left {
  font-size: 1.14em;
  color: #302F2F;
  line-height: 1.647;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">75</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">98</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South Asia</label><span class="pull-right">47</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">53</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">55</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">26</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">78</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">90</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">67</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">88</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The code should be outside of `click` and on page load event as per OP's requirements.

Comment: Your code will not execute anything else that might be in the click function, just add the class

Comment: Didn't you see the differences between my snippet and OP's snippet?

Comment: Yes. You add a class. What if there is more code than just make things grey? Like toggle some text or send an ajax request to fill a select elsewhere? See my code for what I mean

Comment: There is no end of if and else.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

put this after ready to inititialize:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(){
    this.parentNode.classList.add('fltr-chk-box-bg');
});
```

Comment: Your code will not execute anything else that might be in the click function, just add the class

Answer (score 0):

This code will onload also execute all code that runs when the checkbox is clicked.

Instead of just triggering the background color, I run the function since often you have other side effects (show/hide a div or such) when clicked.

Also note the use of toggleClass

```js
function whenClicked() {
  $(this).closest("div").toggleClass("fltr-chk-box-bg",this.checked);
  // anything else that should happen on click
}
$(function() {
  $(".checkbox-primary").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", whenClicked);
  // not quite sure why I could not just trigger click on the above  
  // but have to run an each 
  $(".checkbox-primary input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(whenClicked);
});
```

```css
.checkbox {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.checkbox>label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #686868;
  padding-top: 2px;
  min-height: 25px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.checkbox>span {
  padding-right: 17px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:disabled+label::before {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-circle label::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.checkbox.checkbox-inline {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.fltr-chk-box-bg {
  background-color: #E3E7EA;
  color: #1E6C97;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #1E6C97;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.checkbox-primary input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  color: #fff;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 75456;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label+span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 13px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-top: 11px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-right: 50px solid #CCD2D6;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  z-index: -7523;
}

.fltr-panel-group {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.fltr-panel {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.fltr-panel:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.fltr-panel-title>a {
  padding: 18px 8px 19px 8px;
  font-size: 1.21em;
  color: #2B3439;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel.fltr-panel {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.panel-group.fltr-panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body.fltr-panel-body {
  border-top: none;
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset {
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.fltr-and-reset a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0.78em;
}

.fltr-and-reset>.pull-right {
  font-size: 1.07em;
  color: #1E6C97;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}

.fltr-and-reset>.text-left {
  font-size: 1.14em;
  color: #302F2F;
  line-height: 1.647;
  font-family: 'montserrat';
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">75</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">98</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South Asia</label><span class="pull-right">47</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">53</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">55</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">26</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">23</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">78</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">90</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>North America</label><span class="pull-right">67</span>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    <label>South America</label><span class="pull-right">88</span>
  </div>
</form>
```